# match `>` only from non tag type string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to match `>` character from the input string only if it is not bind as an HTML tag.

For example:
Input: `abc>` should match the `>` char, but
Input: `</abc>` should not match the `>` char, also
Input: `<abc`> should not match the `>` char.

So far I've come upto this regex:

```
/(?<![a-z])>/g
```

Checkout the example at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9OcFiX/1)

The regex is not catching some expected matches.

Using the negative look behind, can I avoid an expression?

Expected match:

```
<a> (x)
</a> (x)
<tag> (x)
</tag> (x)
<<< (x)
>>> (match)
< > (match)
<;> (match)
a<a a> aa (match)
<a title="one">one</a> (x)
title="one">one</a> (just one match after ")
```

Comment: Try `(?<!<\/?\w[^<>]*)>`

Comment: thx. matches every expected case. let me try some more cases.

Comment: But `<a a>` should not match, it is an `a` tag with an `a` attribute. If you want to detect tags with valid attribute names, you will have to enumerate all known valid attributes then.

Answer (score 2):

Using a case insensitive match using `/i` and lookbehind support, you might use:

```
(?<!<\/?[a-z]+\d*)>
```

Note that this assumes that there are no spaces matching the tag.

**Explanation**

- `(?<!` Negative lookahead

  - `<\/?` Match `<` with optional `?`
  - `[a-z]+\d*` match 1+ chars a-z and optional digits
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `>` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pPuflO/1)

Comment: This won't work if the tag contains attributes. OP did not provide such an example, but HTML tags can have attributes in general.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, that is why it added `Note that this assumes that there are no spaces matching the tag.` because of this `a<a a> aa`

Comment: thx for the answer. I've added more examples with tags containing attrs. Actually the point is correct, tags containing attrs. should not be a match for `>`

Comment: @pKiran So you are trying to parse html with a regex in Javascript and want to find `>` ? What do you want to do with the match? Perhaps you are better off using a DOM parser, finding the text nodes and check for a `>` Another option might be using  a capture groupo and a match with an alternation. `(<\/?[a-z][^<>]*>)|>` See https://regex101.com/r/SXfAk9/1

Comment: I'm building a markdown parser. This is for escaping angle brackets which are not bind as a tag. See https://github.com/kiranparajuli589/md-parser/blob/main/lib/util/esc.js